# Facebook analytics for apps do not return any data using export api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-analytics

I am using Facebook analytics for apps and I want to get my data of a particular date but I am only getting the app events name and not their count and anything else

```
{
  "data": [
{
  "id": 259755087814076,
  "start_ts": "2017-02-18T00:00:00+0000",
  "end_ts": "2017-02-18T23:53:20+0000",
  "status": "RUNNING",
  "column_names": [
    "server_time",
    "event_name",
    "client",
    "app_version",
    "numeric_data",
    "event_log_time",
    "custom1",
    "custom2",
    "custom3",
    "custom4",
    "custom5",
    "custom6",
    "custom7",
    "custom8",
    "custom9",
    "custom10",
    "custom11",
    "custom12",
    "custom13",
    "custom14",
    "custom15",
    "custom16",
    "custom17",
    "custom18",
    "custom19",
    "custom20",
    "custom21",
    "custom22",
    "custom23",
    "custom24",
    "custom25",
    "analytics_app_id",
    "ad_tracking_enabled",
    "usd_amount",
    "ext_user_agent",
    "ext_device_model",
    "ext_device_os",
    "timezone",
    "ext_carrier",
    "screen_dimensions",
    "total_disk_gb",
    "remaining_disk_gb",
    "invoking_ui_element",
    "is_device_id_anonymous",
    "raw_advertiser_id"
  ],
  "event_param_names": [
    {
      "event_name": "fb_page_view"
    },
    {
      "event_name": "fb_web_new_user",
      "param_names": [
        "original_event",
        "segments",
        "untruncated_event"
      ]
    },
    {
      "event_name": "Google Login"
    },
    {
      "event_name": "Login"
    },
    {
      "event_name": "SignUp"
    },
    {
      "event_name": "Facebook Login"
    }
```

Will I be able to get the counts or I will get only the app events name and not the data

Answer (score 0):

Based on the JSON you pasted.
Looks like your export job is still running:  "status": "RUNNING"
As part of the export API, one can export and download the last 30 days of RAW events data. See in the link below list of exported fields for each event:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/export

Comment: I followed the same steps as mentioned in the docs but still not able to get the data . if you could send me the snapshots of your work it would be helpful for me